# How can my Greasemonkey script find links with a specific pattern?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, greasemonkey

My target page has some links like:

```
http://example.com/ref.php?564646
```

where the number varies.

How can I find these links and show them at the top of the page using a Greasemonkey script?

Comment: Loop through the [links collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.links), build up the links that match your needs then you can use `<element>.clone()` and add them to the body element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search on arbitrary patterns of link `href`s, use the awesome power of *jQuery* and *Regular Expressions* (RegEx).

Then use jQuery to add the cloned links and use `GM_addStyle()` to position and style everything.

Here is **a complete script** that shows the process.  You can also [**see the code in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4HuZ/1/) :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Use jQuery and RegEx to match arbitrary links
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

//--- Add a custom, regex-aware href selector
jQuery.extend (
    jQuery.expr[':'].hrefMatch = function (elem, J, Mtch, candidateNodeArry) {
        if (elem.hasAttribute ("href") ) {
            var zRegExp = new RegExp (Mtch[3], 'i');

            return zRegExp.test (elem.href);
        }

        return false;
    }
);

//-- Find links that match "ref.php?{some integer}"
matchedLinks = $("a:hrefMatch('ref\\.php\\?\\d+(?!\\w)')");

//-- Now add the links to the top of the page.
$("body").append ('<div id="gmMatchedLinks"></div>');
matchedLinks.clone (true, false). appendTo ("#gmMatchedLinks");

//-- Position the new links and style to taste.
GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
    #gmMatchedLinks a {                         \
        margin-right: 2em;                      \
    }                                           \
    #gmMatchedLinks {                           \
        position:   fixed;                      \
        top:        0px;                        \
        left:       0px;                        \
        background: orange;                     \
        padding:    1em;                        \
        z-index:    555;                        \
    }                                           \
" );
```

Comment: Add `display: block;` to the CSS for `#gmMatchedLinks a`.  See http://jsfiddle.net/d4HuZ/6/.